# Entity Framework Core / postgresql / "Connection is busy"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5, npgsql

I wanted to optimize the following code to reduce memory consumption as
`query` results can in some cases be very large (~4M rows).

`query.ToListAsync()` will load the whole data into memory first and then start `foreach` interation. In order to reduce memory I wanted to use `streaming` instead of `buffered` approach and removed `.ToListAsync()` but now I get the exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Connection is busy
```

The query that works but consumes lot of memory

```
var query =
    from foo in _context.Foos.AsNoTracking()
    where !_context.Bars.Any(bar => bar.FooId == foo.Id)
    select foo;

var buffer = new List<Bar>(BUFFERSIZE);
foreach(var foo in await query.ToListAsync(cancellationToken))
{
    buffer.Add(new Bar(foo)
    {
        //Additional initialization
    });
    
    if (buffer.Count == BUFFERSIZE)
    {
        _context.Bars.AddRange(buffer);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        _context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
        buffer = new List<Bar>(BUFFERSIZE);
    }
}                            

await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Streaming version that does not work:

```
var query =
    from foo in _context.Foos.AsNoTracking()
    where !_context.Bars.Any(bar => bar.FooId == foo.Id)
    select foo;

var buffer = new List<Bar>(BUFFERSIZE);
foreach(var foo in query)
{
    buffer.Add(new Bar(foo)
    {
        //Additional initialization
    });
    
    if (buffer.Count == BUFFERSIZE)
    {
        _context.Bars.AddRange(buffer);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);  //throws System.InvalidOperationException: Connection is busy
        _context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
        buffer = new List<Bar>(BUFFERSIZE);
    }
}                            

await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

- What is wrong?
- Should I use two separate contexts one for reading
  and the other for writing?
- Can't EF Core handle such case where
  results are streaming back and we make data writes, or is `Npqsql`
  related?

Comment: It is not news that EF is not ready for Bulk Operations.  What you are trying to do? Copy big amount of records to the same table?

Comment: You can read it from the query. I insert new records based on not exist join. I cannpt use bulk insert EF extensions (postgresql+ postgis) , nor do it easily on the server side (need some client processing before insert)

Comment: 1) Why do not limit selected records by, for example `Take(1000)` and process everything in loop 2) If client side processing can be expressed by SQL, we can do that by extension in single query.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I was hoping I can run away from paging but you are right, it would help. Ad 2) it could be done, but it means placing some logic in SQL procedures which I would rather avoid, Do you know why "Connection is busy" is thrown? Can't save new records while fetching other query results on the same context?

Comment: Well, not sure but as I know PostgreSQL(NPgsql) do not support MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets). So you cannot enumerate records on opened DataReader and use the same connection to save data. IOW, you have to load everything via `ToList` and only then you can call `SaveChanges`. It may help if you create two DbContext one for read, another for write.

Comment: First, this doesn't seem to be related to bulk operations as suggested by @svyatoslav-danyliv above. Otherwise, yes - your options are either to buffer the query results before executing SaveChangesAsync, or use two contexts.

Comment: This would almost certainly be a MARS issue as Svyatoslav points out. The connection would be in-use when iterating so subsequent reads or SaveChanges() would not be allowed. Multiple DbContexts might be an option but you have to be careful if your new Bar contains any reference to the read Foo. I see you are loading the Foo `AsNoTracking()` so detached, whether using 1 context or 2, saving a Bar containing a reference (navigation property) to that Foo would either result in an error or duplicate data. Ultimately bulk-like operations should be tackled in pages or use something other than EF.

Comment: It's important to note that the above isn't necessary possible as a SQL bulk operation (UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE). If the initialization of Bar contains any .NET logic (anything that can't be expressed in SQL), then there's is no alternative apart from loading entities to the client and saving them back as above. If the Bar logic is expressible in SQL, than a single WITH can perform that very efficiently (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)